# Closedness of the set of probability measures anihilating a measurable function

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X$ be a compact metrizable topological space and let $f$
be a bounded, real valued, Borel function on $X$.  Denoting by
$P(X)$ the collection of all probability measures on $X$,
consider the subset
  $$
  Z(f):= \left\{μ∈P(X): \int_X fdμ=0\right\}.
  $$

> Question: What is the most general condition one should require of $f$
>   to ensure that $Z(f)$ is closed in the weak* topology of $P(X)$ (seen
>   within the dual Banach space of $C(X)$).

For obvious reasons $Z(f)$ is closed when $f$ is continuous,
but it is also closed if, say, $f$ is the pointwise limit of an increasing
sequence $\{f_n\}_n$ of non-negative continuous functions
(hence lower semi-continuous).  This is because
  $$
  Z(f) = \bigcap_nZ(f_n),
  $$
  so $Z(f)$ is closed.

On the other hand, if the Borel subset $A⊆X$ is not open, there
exists a sequence $\{x_n\}_n$ in the complement of $A$,
converging to a point $p$ in $A$.  In this case the Dirac
measures $δ_{x_n}$ all lie in $Z(1_A)$ (by $1_A$ I mean the
characteristic function of $A$), and they converge weak*ly to
$δ_p$, which isn't in $Z(1_A)$.  Therefore $Z(1_A)$ is not
closed!

Comment: Another trivial example is when $f$ is any strictly positive (resp., strictly negative) Borel function, for then we have $Z(f) = \emptyset$.  This shows that the answer can't really have to do with the regularity of $f$.

Comment: @NateEldredge, you are right.  The answer will likely be a combination of positivity and regularity.  Incidentally, the case I am mostly interested in involves a function $f$ of the form $g-h$, where both $g$ and $h$ are non-negative, $g$ is continuous, and $h$ is upper-continuous.

Comment: if one assumes $f$ to be non-negative, then I'd say that $Z(f)$ is closed if and only if the lower semicontinuous envelope of $f$ (i.e. the maximal lsc function $\leq f$) has the same zeros of $f$. Not sure if this helps for the case $g-h$ mentioned above

Answer (score -1):

It is a fact, well-known and elementary, that a linear functional on a locally convex space is continuous if and only if its kernel is closed.

Comment: This is true, but I don't see how it helps answer the question?  $P(X)$ isn't a vector space.